# Javascript to set value of ID in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Are you allowed to set the ID of an HTML element dynamically - i.e. as a simple example, can i do:

```
<a href="#" id="onOrOff()">Jazz</a>
```

And:

```
function onOrOff()
{
 document.write("someIDSetInMyCSSFile");    
}
```

I've tried it and it doesnt work so just want to check whether or not I'm missing some other point.

Thanks.

Comment: You can but this isn't the way to do it.

Comment: You should explain at what stage you'd like to set it dynamically, and possibly why you want to do that. You can change most properties of an object at run-time, however you first need to be able to get a handle to that object. The answer below will work for the first 'A' tag on your page, which may or may not work for you.

Comment: True.  My own answer does not have this problem as I use and id for the A element and then show how to change it.  However, I will stress again here that I think it is good practice to give ids and never ever change them, but instead change the css classes in order to achieve the desired effect.  Even if it means changing an existing CSS stylesheet slightly (e.g. #coolLink -> .coolLink) this is a much better solution in most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Created a jsFiddle for this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/SdvA2/3/  Feel free to experiment!

Assuming that your CSS refers to #coolLink (and/or #uncoolLink)you could try something like this:

```
<a href="#" id="uncoolLink" onclick="makeCool()">Jazz</a>
```

To turn on coolLink id formatting dynamically you can try using these functions:

```
<script>
function makeCool() {
  var element = document.getElementById("uncoolLink");
  element.id ="coolLink";
}
</script>
```

See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById

However, I would strongly recommend keeping the id constant and simply changing the class (and adjusting your css accordingly).

Going one step further, I would recommend using jQuery as this will open up a world of possibility, change the way you approach things, make life so much easier and protect you from browser incompatibilities.

Comment: Hi Miltiadis - thanks for your help on this (btw that jsFiddle site is awesome!). However i don't think that approach solves my problem. I'll describe exactly what it is I'm trying to achieve. I have some tags, when a tag is pressed (switched on) the it should be one css style, when it is pressed again (switched off) it should be another style. These styles would also need to be carried across to other pages. E.g. I have an array of selected tags, so when the next page opens anything in that array should have the 'On' css style.

Comment: Actually no worries - i figured it out. I ended up using that document.getElementById, along with some functions and CSS - learning so much :-) Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but not like that. You would need some other way to access it, for instance:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
```

Then:

```
a.id = "myDynamicID";
```

Comment: Ok - good to know however I'm not sure how I would implement the above. My function onOrOff() does some 'work' before deciding which ID to use?

Comment: You can do that. The important thing is to assign to the element's "id" property.

Comment: If you have a page with multiple links it is entirely impractical to look for the A element by means of getElementsByTagName[someIndexThatMightChangeIfAnotherAIsAddedToThePage] !!! Still your answer deserved an upvote for the a.id = "myDynamicID" part :-)